# Transaction not active after migrating legacy application to JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. I'd like to upgrade the Hibernate configuration in a legacy application to a JPA configuration, still using Hibernate as underlying implementation. Versions are: Hibernate 4.3.11 and Spring 4.2.4.

Configuration is in XML and for clarity split into smaller configuration files:

**datasource.xml**

```
<bean id="hibernateDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/my-db"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

**entity-manager.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="hibernateDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" ref="hibernatePackagesToScan"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="connection.isolation">2</prop>
                <prop key="export">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"/>
                <prop key="hibernate.mapping.precedence">class, hbm</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">com.myapp.MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">SCHEMA</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.myapp.MyTenantProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- For use in beans that depend on session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="hibernatePackagesToScan" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>com.myapp.model</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**transaction-manager.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

DAO's extend an AbstractDao which looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession()
    {
        try
        {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        catch (org.hibernate.HibernateException e)
        {
            return sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
    }
}
```

All requests to the webapp go through the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.

On the first request, a DAO is called fetching some configuration from the database using simple Criteria:

```
@Override
public ApplicationSettings getSettings()
{
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(ApplicationSettings.class);
    return (ApplicationSettings) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

This call results in a HibernateException with message: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction.

What could I have missed here?

Comment: Since the config adds `annotation-driven`, I'd suggest to add the `@Transactional` annotation to your `getSettings` method.

Comment: That doesn’t work, unfortunately. Not really a solution to the problem, read only queries shouldn’t require transactions...

Comment: Sorry that this didn't help. As for the "read only queries shouldn't require transactions" - there are some good reasons to have read-only transactions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818074/transactions-for-read-only-db-access